# Changing state of JQuery Mobile Calendar dates in code (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

The tutorial at:

http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/demos/calendar/blackhigh.html

explains how to disable/highlight days in HTML.

Is there a neat way to do this at runtime - i.e with JavaScript, preferably without manually adding/removing classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set disable dates through js like this

```
$('#mydate').data('datebox').options.blackDates = ['2012-01-01','2012-01-06'];
```

and highlight dates like this

```
$('#mydate').data('datebox').options.highDates = ['2012-01-10','2012-01-12'];
```

Demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/jj8th/

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that. I had to call $('#mydate').datebox("refresh"); before the changes showed up though, any idea why that is?

Comment: Glad to be of help..Are you hiding the textinput and just showing the calendar component?.In that case you probably have to trigger a refresh for changes to show up.